# How to open a specific URL onclick?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a URL when the following is clicked:

```
<span class="taglib-text">Forgot Password</span>
```

Can anybody provide me with its Javascript?

Actually, I cannot control the HTML that's why I need to call an event using Javascript and class name i.e. `taglib-text`

Comment: set `window.location = url`

Comment: What do you want to use jQuery for @marcos1490? @user1980107: You can't control the HTML, but you can add JavaScript? iframe?

Comment: @putvande Because he has no control over the HTML.

Comment: @ShawnGrav, still I don't see a need for jQuery over JavaScript to open a URL.

Comment: @putvande I agree with you ther, I was just answering why the HTML could not be edited

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('taglib-text')[0]; // only targets the first element it finds
element.addEventListener('click',function(){
    location.href = url;
});
```

If you have many elements with that class you can instead use:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('taglib-text');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        location.href = url;
    });
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/25fJA/)

I changed my answer from using `.querySelector()` to `.getElementsByClassName()` because of Shawn's comment and [this test](http://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/18)

Comment: why not use `document.getElementsByClassName()`? I mean, your answer is correct +1, but from what I know `.querySelector()` only pulls in a static list of elements as opposed to `.getElementsByClassName()` which pulls in a live list of elements.

Comment: @ShawnGrav, good point. Edited answer.

Comment: It does not work. Can you create an HTML example using JSFiddle?

Comment: @user1980107 I fixed an error in the code, he had a period in his `.getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Please help. I'm still not able to use it.

Comment: @Sergio, you should remove the period in `getElementsByClassName`'s string argument, as pointed out by Shawn Grav.

Comment: @MasterAM, thanks. Introduced a bug by changing to `.getElementsByClassName()` and then went to bed :) Corrected!

Comment: @ShawnGrav,  Introduced a bug by changing to .getElementsByClassName() and then went to bed :) Not so good... Corrected!

Comment: @user1980107, added a fiddle example. Wrapped the code in a window.onload function, in case your problem is that you are running the javascript before your html is ready/loaded.